# How to prevent unwanted elements from moving on hover in CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

In the organization chart below, when you hover over an element in A, B or C column, there is a weird thing happening. The lines and boxes after hovered element are moving down as the hovered element is changing size, but after it has finished resizing, those lines and boxes return to previous position. (I want to keep this position always, even during resizing of an hovering element)

Can anyone help me fix this?

Code:

```css
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
    transition: all linear 1s;
}

.tree{
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;       
    padding: 0;
}

ul a{
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 11px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 90px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

img {
    width: 29%;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px 0 0 6px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

a:hover{
    font: bold 11.5px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

a:hover span{
    font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover > img{
    width: 30%;
    height: 90px;
}

.tree span{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.leader{
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.leader:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 0 0 -20px 50%;
}

.leader a{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 85%;
}

.leader a:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
}

.teams{
    margin-left: -3%;
}

.teams li{
    float: left;
    width: 30.3%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.teams:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 66.5%;
    height: 20px;   
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    margin-left: 18%;
}

.team li{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.team a{
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.team li a{
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.team > a:first-child{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.employees li{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.employees li:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    width: 9%;
}

.employees li:nth-child(1n+2):before{
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -43px;
}

.employees li a{
    width: 90%;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -47px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.employees li a:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    height: 100px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: -52px 0 -48px 5%;
}
```

```html
<body ondragstart="return false">
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="leader"><a href="#">Leader</a></li>
        <ul class="teams">
            <li class="team a"><a href="#">A</a>
                <ul class="employees">
                    <li><a href="#">A1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">A4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="team b"><a href="#">B</a>
                <ul class="employees">
                    <li><a href="#">B1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="team c"><a href="#">C</a>
                <ul class="employees">
                    <li><a href="#">C1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using transform:scale(x) for the hover effect instead of actually changing the element size. Transform does not affect the overall layout so the surrounding elements stay where they are. Also transforms don't cause the browser to repaint and can use the GPU for the animating process so they are generally much smoother.

Comment: Yes that looks almost as I wanted. But now when the hovered element scales itself, at the end it shakes a bit (1px down and up). Also the border is little bit blurred. Is there any way to fix this as well?